# Multiple serializers for a single model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a `User` model that hasMany `Reminders`.

When a `User` is first created, I want the `reminders` to be embedded. When it is updated, I don't want its reminders to be embedded. How can I do this?

My strategy was to create a custom `new-user-serializer` that had `DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin` and

```
reminders: { embedded: 'always' }
```

and use that in my `UserAdapter`s `createRecord` method, but I couldn't get it working.

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 0):

It's not ideal, but you can do it -

```
`import DS from 'ember-data'`
`import ApplicationSerializer from './application'`

UserSerializer = ApplicationSerializer.extend DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin,

    attrs:
        reminders: {}

    serialize: (snapshot, options) ->
        if snapshot.attr('embedRemindersFlag')
            @attrs.reminders.embedded = 'always'
        @_super(snapshot, options)

`export default UserSerializer`
```

`embedRemindersFlag` has to be an attribute of the model so snapshot picks it up, but I have separately implemented a `transient` option which prevents an attribute from being sent to the server.

```
embedRemindersFlag: DS.attr 'string', {defaultValue: false, transient: true}
```