# Can I POST multiple models using Ember Data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

So let's say you have a User model which is set up to a fairly standard API. On the front end you have an Ember project which also has that User model. The normal creation call would be something like the following:

```
store.createRecord('user', {email: 'test@gmail.com'}).save();
```

This would send off a POST request to something like `/api/users`. However, something fairly extensive API's support is the creation of multiple models at once. So for instance, instead of the POST call just sending a single object under `user: {email: 'test@gmail.com'}` it would send an array of objects like `users: [{email: 'test@gmail.com'}, {email: 'test2@gmail.com'}, ...]`.

How I have seen this handled in ember is to just do multiple creation calls at runtime. However, this is terribly inefficient and I am wondering if Ember supports saving multiple models at the same time? How would you achieve this in Ember?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot save an array of models in a single POST request Ember Data as you describe it, however there is a way.

You can save a parent model which `hasMany 'user'` with the [EmbeddedRecordsMixin](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html), which will include either relationship ids or full records.  Your serializer would look like -

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  attrs: {
    users: { embedded: 'always' },
  }
});
```

Depending on your use case it may make sense to create a parent model only for this purpose which `hasMany 'user'`.  If you want to use an existing model and don't always want to embed its user records there is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33570672/1396904).

If you do decide to save the models individually, you would want to do `users.invoke('save')`, which will trigger a POST for each model.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking specifically about Ember Data, I don't know of any way of doing that (I don't think it's possible to use any equivalent of save() on a collection/array). There could be alternative Data libraries that may work (for instance you could check [Orbit.JS](https://github.com/orbitjs/orbit.js) - which is something I haven't done yet)

The way I've done it it to have a custom endpoint on my backend that receives a certain JSON payload and creates the resources. You do it by issuing a regular ajax call, see this example (from a project of mine).

```
let content = //get content that you want to post
let accessToken = this.get('session.session.authenticated.token');
Ember.$.ajax({
    data: JSON.stringify(content),
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'path/to/my/custom/end/point',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Beader ${accessToken}`
    }
  }).then((result) => {
    // Code for success
  }, (jqXHR) => {
    // Code for error
  }).always(() => {
    // Code for always/finally
  });
```

As you can see this is all custom code, not leveraging Ember Data store or models. So far I haven't found a better answer.

EDIT: After seeing andorov's answer. I forgot to mention something. I'm using Ember Data 2.0 (JSONAPI by default) and [EmbeddedRecordsMixin does not work](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/3720) property with JSON API